# Upload to S3 using PHP SDK, signature doesn't match?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is my function to upload to S3 using PHP.  I get this  error:

**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.**

I'm using the correct key and secret.  What have i done wrong?

```
 function upload_s3bucket($file,$name,$bucket) {
        require(APPPATH.'/third_party/aws/aws-autoloader.php');
        $key = "*******";
        $secret = "************";
        $file = "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/website/assets/media/images/test.jpg";

        if(isset($file)){

            $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
                'region'  => 'us-east-1',
                'version' => 'latest',
                'credentials' => [
                    'key'    => $key,
                    'secret' => $secret,
                ]
            ]);     

            $result = $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket' => 'cdn-example.com/'.$bucket,
                'Key'    => $key,
                'SourceFile' => $file,
                'ACL'   => 'public-read'    
            ]);

            return $file_name;

        }

    }
```

Is the Object Key the same as Access Key?  I'm using Access Key that i created from "Your Security Credentials".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not the same the S3 Object key refers to a folder in an S3 bucket i.e s3://mybucket/mykey

The credential key is your access key and secret key.